# How to do ripple effect based on voice frequency in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, voice, voice-recording

I work on a voice recording project on flutter and I want to implement ripple effect based on user's input voice frequency like the example below.

[image]

I've been searching for it but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone guide me on how I would do it?